# Python: why not age calculation using datetime.fromordinal?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm kinda new to programming and I was wondering, is it possible to use the method `datetime.fromordinal` to calculate age? I know that it wasn't made for that, and there's a different between an age and a date.
I've looked around and didn't find anyone suggesting this method. So would a code like this work well and be reliable (for all cases I mean)? I've ran few test and the results were OK. Is it advise to use this method or not?

```
from datetime import date

def calc_age(birthday=date(2000,2,29)):
    """returns the age as an integer value, given the birthday as a datetime.date object"""
    today=date.today()
    days=(today-birthday).days
    if (birthday.year%4):
        days-=364
    else:
        days-=365

    return date.fromordinal(days).year
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach might work in most cases, but I see two problems.

1. `date.fromordinal` is designed to return an actual date, not a relative number of years
2. Not every 4th year is a leap year (e.g. 1900 wasn't)

A better approach might be to just subtract the years and allow for whether the birthday has passed or not, so you leave the leapyear logic in the hands of datetime.

```
from datetime import date

def calc_age(birthday=date(2000,2,29)):
    today = date.today()
    age_on_this_year_birthday = today.year - birthday.year
    this_year_birthday = date(today.year, birthday.month, birthday.day)
    if today >= this_year_birthday:
        return age_on_this_year_birthday
    else:
        return age_on_this_year_birthday - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another module that you can use that's good for dates; it's **arrow**. What would you say to this?

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.get(2000,2,29).humanize()
'17 years ago'
```

In this case *humanize* is comparing the given date with the current date and time but there is an additional parameter that permits one to make comparisons with any date and time.

See http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/